# Using PSR-0 in composer.json does not load my classes

Tags: composer-php, autoload, psr-0

In `composer.json` I have the following data:

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "2.*",
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "lib": "lib/"
        }
    }
}
```

`lib` folder resides beside `vendor` folder. Inside of lib I have a class named `Decorator.php` and my class name is `Decorator` as below:

```
namespace lib;
class Decorator
{
    public function OutputDecorate()
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

I ran `php compooser.phar update` and get the message `Nothing to install or update blah blah blah`.

And to have a better understanding, this is a part of project folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

Now when I want ti instantiate my class I cannot access my class.

```
use lib;
class Collection {

public $decorator;

public function __construct() {
    $this->decorator = new Decorator();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be doing:

```
use lib\Decorator;
```

if you want to be able to do `new Decorator();` in your code.

The PHP use statement only includes a single class, it doesn't import whole namespaces.

Are you a recovering Java programmer?

Also for PSR-0, the declaration in the composer.json of where classes are needs to point at containing directory not the top level namespace. e.g. I think it should be:

```
"psr-0": {
    "lib": "./"
}
```

or

```
"psr-0": {
    "lib": ""
}
```

Comment: It still fails: `Fatal error: Class 'lib\Decorator' not found in /home/hosseini/atrisa/faxir_core/www/html/slim/index.php on line 24`

Comment: I corrected the path to `"lib": "./"` and issued the command `composer.phar update`. Voila!

Answer (score 0):

I used psr-4 instead and then my classes are loading perfectly.

Here is my composer.json.

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
              "ComposerTest\\Models\\": "App/Models",
             },
  }
}
```

And the Folder structure is

-->App

-->Models

```
 -->Product.php
```

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an
answer really needs a bit more detail than this.  Please
[edit] to provide example code to show what you mean.
Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.